# Calling postMessage on iframeElement in flutter web

Tags: flutter, events, iframe

I have a flutter web application. I need to call postMessage to be handled by the page opened in an iframe element using

```
 ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
            'hello-world-html',
            (int viewId) => html.IFrameElement()
              ..width = '100%'
              ..height = '100%'
              ..src = widget.url
              ..style.border = 'none'
              );
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, PostMessage sends to the main document's window, not to the iframe's.

Specify the iframe's window object in Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('hello-world-html').contentWindow.postMessage(.......)
```

or in Dart you can do:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

// Your code

html.document.getElementById.getElementById('hello-world-html').contentWindow.postMessage(.......)
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for an iframe that has a cross domain src

```
import 'dart:html';

 IFrameElement element = document.getElementById('iframe') as IFrameElement;
               element.contentWindow?.postMessage(data.toJson(),'*');
```

Comment: I tried to call `postMessage()` on `onload()` after iframe loaded.  `onLoad` called but not posting message. Same If if do in button click then it worked. Any thoughts?
```
IFrameElement iframeElement = IFrameElement()
      ..id = 'iframe'
      ..src = 'http://localhost:3000/'
      ..onLoad.listen((Event event) {
        IFrameElement element =
            document.getElementById('dicom') as IFrameElement;
        const config = {
        };
        element.contentWindow!.postMessage(config, '*');
      });
```