How to send information from flutter to html file
The goal is to send data from flutter to the script field in html.
I think the data is being send and received by html file but i cant get a handle on the data.
the goal is for the script field (html file) to use the data send from the user in the auto complete.
code1:
MonacoEditorWidget(objects: {"current":{"name":"b"}, },)

code2:
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

class MonacoEditorWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> objects;

  MonacoEditorWidget({Key? key, required this.objects}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MonacoEditorWidgetState createState() => _MonacoEditorWidgetState();
}

class _MonacoEditorWidgetState extends State<MonacoEditorWidget> {
  late StreamSubscription<html.MessageEvent> _messageSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Send the objects to the iframe for code suggestion
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      html.window.postMessage({
        'type': 'initMonaco',
        'objects': jsonEncode(widget.objects)
      }, '*');
    });

    // Listen for messages from the iframe
    _messageSubscription = html.window.onMessage.listen((event) {
      print('Message received from iframe: ${event.data}');
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _messageSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // iFrame
    final String iframeId = 'monaco-editor-container';

    // Create iframe element
    final html.IFrameElement iframeElement = html.IFrameElement()
      ..src = 'monaco_editor.html'
      ..style.border = 'none';

    // Register iframe
    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      iframeId,
      (int viewId) => iframeElement,
    );

    return HtmlElementView(viewType: iframeId);
  }
}

code3(script field /html file):

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Load the Monaco Editor Loader Script -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.47.0/min/vs/loader.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-ZG31AN9z/CQD1YDDAK4RUAvogwbJHv6bHrumrnMLzdCrVu4HeAqrUX7Jsal/cbUwXGfaMUNmQU04tQ8XXl5Znw=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <style>
    body,
    html {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      /* Establishes a flex container */
      overflow: hidden;
      /* Prevents unwanted overflow */
    }

    #editorArea,
    #output {
      flex: 1;
      /* This ensures both the editor area and output take up equal space */
      min-width: 0;
      /* Prevents flex items from growing beyond their content size, allowing shrinking */
    }

    #editorArea {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      overflow: hidden;
      /* Ensures overflow content in the editor is scrollable */
    }

    #toolbar {
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    #editorContainer {
      flex-grow: 1;
      overflow: auto;
      /* Allows scrolling within the editor if content overflows */
    }

    #container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      /* Ensures the editor uses the full available area */
    }

    #outputArea {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex: 1;
      /* Equal width with the editor area */
      overflow: hidden;
      /* Hide overflow */
    }

    #outputToolbar {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }


    #output {
      flex-grow: 1;
      padding: 10px;
      overflow: auto;
      /* Make output scrollable */
      border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
      /* Visual separation */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="editorArea">
    <div id="toolbar">
      <select id="languageSelector">
        <option value="javascript">JavaScript</option>
  
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="editorContainer">
      <div id="container"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="outputArea">
    <div id="outputToolbar">
      <button id="runCodeButton">Run</button>
      <button id="exitEditorButton" style="float: right;">Exit Editor</button>
    </div>
    <div id="output">Output will appear here...</div>
  </div>



  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      require.config({
        paths: {
          'vs': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.47.0/min/vs'
        }
      });
      require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function () {
        var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
          value: "// Your code here",
          language: 'javascript',
          theme: 'vs-dark',
          automaticLayout: true
        });

        // Listen for changes in the language selector and update the editor
        document.getElementById('languageSelector').addEventListener('change', function () {
          var newLanguage = this.value;
          monaco.editor.setModelLanguage(editor.getModel(), newLanguage);
        });
      });

      document.getElementById('runCodeButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Save the original console.log
        const originalConsoleLog = console.log;

        // Clear the output window before each run
        document.getElementById('output').textContent = '';

        // Override console.log
        console.log = function (...args) {
          // Display output in the UI's output window
          document.getElementById('output').textContent += args.join(' ') + '\n';
          // Optionally call the original console.log to see output in the browser console as well
          // originalConsoleLog.apply(console, args);
        };

        try {
          // Get the current code from the Monaco editor
          const userCode = monaco.editor.getModels()[0].getValue();

          // Evaluate the user's code
          eval(userCode);
        } catch (e) {
          // If an error occurs, display it in the output window
          document.getElementById('output').textContent = 'Error: ' + e.message;
        } finally {
          // Restore the original console.log
          console.log = originalConsoleLog;
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>

this is the output i see::
Restarted application in 27ms.
The debugEmulateFlutterTesterEnvironment getter is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `debugEmulateFlutterTesterEnvironment` from `dart:ui_web` instead.
The platformViewRegistry getter is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please import it from `dart:ui_web` instead.
Height of Platform View type: [monaco-editor-container] may not be set. Defaulting to `height: 100%`.
Set `style.height` to any appropriate value to stop this message.
Width of Platform View type: [monaco-editor-container] may not be set. Defaulting to `width: 100%`.
Set `style.width` to any appropriate value to stop this message.
22
{type: initMonaco, objects: {"current":{"name":"b"}}}
17
Message received from iframe: {type: initMonaco, objects: {"current":{"name":"b"}}}

it appears that the data is being received somehow by the html, but i cant get a handle on it.
is it possible to do this?
these are my dependecies::
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
js: ^0.7.1
flutter_js: ^0.8.1
i found this medium article that might help, didnt help me :(
https://medium.com/@andcachia/communication-between-flutter-iframe-and-html-parent-9fd7acd33ebf

Could you check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71479637/2179571 and https://gist.github.com/kenzieschmoll/36211ccaf7e1c16dca43c3fbf60243f1
